# Route 100% traffic to staging before swapping deployment slots?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, blue-green-deployment

I have an app service in which users will be kicked out when I would swap a staging to production slot. This can't be easily solved because of the outdated architecture. Thinking of a solution, I thought: what if I set the traffic percentage of the staging slot to 100%? Then all new connections will be routed to the new version. Then I could write a process that waits until all connections on the production slot are gone, and then do the swap. This assumes that existing connections on the staging are not touched by the swap, as they are already routed to the IP address of the new version.

Will this approach work? Or is it a waste of time to investigate this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Your approach is correct you can route all your traffic to the Staging slot by setting the traffic percentage to 100%. Also, If you select **`Perform swap with preview option`**. This option warms up the instance before the swap and your swapping happens seamlessly without any drop in the connection. Additionally, While the 100% traffic is routed to staging slot, You can make the process change in the Production slot and while swapping the slots all the settings from your Staging slot will be reflected in the production slot properly.

Refer here- [Set up staging environments - Azure App Service | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots?tabs=portal)

***Traffic set to 100 %:-***

[image]

As the 100% traffic is set to Staging slot, All the traffic is routed to staging slot.

All the settings are added while swapping the slot to avoid any issue in the App:-

[image]

After swapping your settings, all the traffic will be routed to Production Slot seamlessly:-

[image]

Comment: This is still not going to work. 
The official documentation says: "After a client is automatically routed to a specific slot, it's "pinned" to that slot for one hour or until the cookies are deleted."
So, after one hour, traffic can go to the production slot again.
I am switching my approach to developing a logic app that waits until all connections are gone on the production slot, en then do the swap, even if this will take several hours of waiting.
Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots?tabs=portal#route-production-traffic-automatically

Comment: Yes, The Web App is content is cached for sometime, You can make use of Logic App and perform a delay until all connections are sent to the Prod slot.